# How improve my table-cell highlighting scheme?

Tags: website-design, information-graphics, information-design

In my daunting  [**table of market numbers**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain), seconds-by-seconds price changes in the Bid, Ask, and Last columns are highlighted for the user.

Highlighting happens when the page is refreshed: click the refresh button to see, or toggle the auto/man button to select auto-refresh.

The highlighting seems to me amateur (hey! that's me!) and clunky. And garish!

Can you suggest a "nicer" -- more pleasing, artistic, unobtrusive --  design to achieve the effect? Are the highlighting colors not right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the colour is probably fine. After all the whole point is making it poke-you-in-the-eye obvious which values have changed and in what direction, when the array may be one of several the user is monitoring concurently on a multi-screen setup.

Colour also seems consistent with similar displays I've seen. Which might also be considered garish, but if there's a standard think very carefully before diverging.

I would perhaps consider looking at a very brief fade-in, as well as the existing fade-out, and check that the fades are as smooth as possible, they seem a bit jumpy to me.

Also, I see no highlighting on IE8.

Comment: thanks! yes, i'll try your fade-in suggestion: seems a good idea. each fade step is 1/10 second, so maybe 2 steps of fade-in followed by the current fade-out. and i'll work on the jumpiness. also thanks for the additional tags.

Comment: it's smoother now. so smooth, in fact, that i've been admiring it for about the last hour :-)  still experimenting with fade-in.